# Unable to download the AndroidPlot Core Library of androidplot

Tags: android, download, androidplot

Hello,

I am a beginner and I want to learn how this works for which I am using eclipse and was trying to follow the tutorial here

For step2 it says to download latest version of the AndroidPlot Core Library from  here http://androidplot.com/download/ but it says there is problem with download for which it says to download most recent stable snapshot artifacts from here

https://androidplot.jira.com/builds/browse/ANDROIDPLOT-TRUNK-177/artifact but I dont understand which one is the actual AndroidPlot Core Library to download from this link.
And if someone has an  latest version of the AndroidPlot Core Library can you post here so that I can download it.

thanks.

Can someone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, [this is the correct jar](https://androidplot.jira.com/builds/artifact/ANDROIDPLOT-TRUNK/JOB1/build-177/Jars/androidplot-core-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT.jar) to add to your project.

Nick